# Elegant way to delete items in a list which do not has substrings that appear in another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Recently I encountered this problem:

Say there is a list of something I want to process:

```
process_list=["/test/fruit/apple","/test/fruit/pineapple","/test/fruit/banana","/test/tech/apple-pen","/test/animal/python","/test/animal/penguin"]
```

And I want to exclude something using another list, for instance:

```
exclude_list=["apple","python"]
```

The process_list should be like this after I apply the exclude_list to it( any process_list item that contains a sub:

```
["/test/fruit/banana","/test/animal/penguin","/test/fruit/pineapple"]
```

or if the exclude_list is:
`exclude_list=["pen","banana"]`

The process_list should be this after apply the filter:

```
["/test/fruit/apple","/test/fruit/pineapple","/test/animal/python"]
```

So what I was trying at first was:

```
for item in exclude_list:
    for name in (process_list):
        if item in name:
            process_list.remove(name)
```

Of course this didn't work because removing elements from the list while iterating over it using a `for` loop is not permitted. The code only removed the first match and then stopped.

So then I came up a way to do this with another list:

```
deletion_list=[] #Track names that need to be deleted
for item in exclude_list:
    for name in (process_list):
        if item in name:
            deletion_list.append(name)
# A list comprehension
process_list=[ x for x in process_list if x not in deletion_list ]
```

It works, but my guts tell me there may be a more elegant way. Now it need s another list to store the name need to be deleted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use the *list comprehension* expression using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) filter as:

```
# Here: `p` is the entry from `process_list`
#       `e` is the entry from `exclude_list`

>>> [p for p in process_list if all(e not in p for e in exclude_list)]                              
['/test/fruit/banana', '/test/animal/penguin']
```

---

Regarding your statement:

> Of course this didn't work because removing elements from the list while iterating over it using a for loop is not permitted. The code only removed the first match and then stopped.

You could have iterate over the copy of the list as:

```
 for item in list(exclude_list):  # OR, for item in exclude_list[:]:
 #              ^-- Creates new copy ----------------------------^
```

Comment: I'd prefer `... if all(e not in p ...)` as  more clearly conveying the semantics but I convene that's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, it is getting more elegant! By the way, I would suggest you to keep both the `any()` and the `all()` version to be shown in your answer. I prefer to the `all()` version but who knows, someone may be fond of the `any()` version.

Comment: @zyc: It seems like everyone copied `not any` what I mentioned at the first place. Everyone already has that as the part of there answer. In case someone want to explore, they may find it. In my opinion, instead of mentioning all the options, it is better to show the correct way to do it. Too much options just create chaos

Answer (score 4):

Just in addition you can also use regular expression e.g.

```
import re

pattern = '(' + ('|').join(exclude_list) + ')'
list(filter(lambda l : re.search(pattern,l) == None, process_list)) #filter will return iterator in case if you use python 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to get the basename of pathname, use the build-in functon [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to check if the basename is not included in `exclude_list`.

```
import os 

process_list=["/test/fruit/apple","/test/fruit/pineapple","/test/fruit/banana","/test/tech/apple-pen","/test/animal/python","/test/animal/penguin"]

# Case 1
exclude_list=["apple","python"]

l = [s for s in process_list 
        if all(item not in os.path.basename(s) for item in exclude_list)]

print(l)
['/test/fruit/banana', '/test/animal/penguin']

# Case 2
exclude_list=["pen","banana"]

l = [s for s in process_list 
        if all(item not in os.path.basename(s) for item in exclude_list)]

print(l)
['/test/fruit/apple', '/test/fruit/pineapple', '/test/animal/python']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[line for line in lines if not any(word in line for word in words)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to achieve what you want is as follows:

```
[item for item in process_list if not any(exc in item.split('/')[-1] for exc in exclude_list)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [item for item in process_list if not any(exc in item.split('/')[-1] for exc in exclude_list)]
['/test/fruit/banana', '/test/animal/penguin']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work directly with process_list and the list comprehension without any funny behavior you should work with a copy, which is created like this: process_list[:]

```
process_list=["/test/fruit/apple","/test/fruit/pineapple","/test/fruit/banana","/test/tech/apple-pen","/test/animal/python","/test/animal/penguin"]
exclude_list=["apple","python"]
process_list = [x for x in  process_list[:] if not any(y in x for y in exclude_list)]
```