# Is this a generator expression?

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

I asked a question about a list comprehension couple days ago:[Elegant way to delete items in a list which do not has substrings that appear in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791002/elegant-way-to-delete-items-in-a-list-which-do-not-has-substrings-that-appear-in)

Anyway, I got a great answer to my question. It is a list comprehension:

`[p for p in process_list if all(e not in p for e in exclude_list)]`

I get the idea and applied it to my work. But I'm not sure if I get the `e not in p for e in exclude_list` part right. It looks like a generator expression to me but I'm not sure. I think it is better to ask this question in another post.

So is it a generator expression or something else?

Comment: yes it is a generator expression.

Comment: Yes. It is a generator expression: `(this is a generator comprehension)`. `[this is a list comprehension]`

Comment: Within `any()` if you directly pass the expression without `[...]`, it is treated as generator expression

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thx! I was trying to ask you under your answer as a comment and then I guess maybe it is good to ask it as a separate question so more people like me can see it. Thank you!

Comment: @zyc: It was a great idea. Martijn has explained it in very detail over here, may be I won't be able to give you that detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `all(e not in p for e in exclude_list)` is a call containing a generator expression. Generator expressions that are the *only* argument passed to a call can omit the parentheses. Here, that's the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) being called.

From the [*Generator expressions* reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument.

The `all()` function (as well as the companion function [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is often given a generator expression, as this allows for lazy evaluation of a series of tests. Only enough `e not in p` tests are executed to determine the outcome; if there is *any* `e not in p` test that is false, `all()` returns early and no further tests are executed.

Answer (score 2):

Let python tell you what it is:

```
>>> p=[]
>>> exclude_list=[]
>>> type(e not in p for e in exclude_list)
<class 'generator'>
```

Comment: This is a great approach. But I think the thing that got me confused in the first place is passing `e not in p for e in exclude_list` to `all()`. And these parentheses really made me wonder if it is still a generator expression. But now I get it since Martijn explained it in his answer,